# Account Kit no funiciona correctamente

Tags: html5, facebook

Buenas Estoy probando Account view de facebook para autenticar a unos usuarios, pero posterior a ingresar el código que me envian por sms la pagina no redirecciona de regreso, si lo pruebo en mi equipo funciona correctamente pero si lo pruebo en ios o android no funciona. Estoy utilizando la version web ya que la validacion se hace un sitio responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Account kit no funciona con webview, es probable que si realizas la prueba con safari en el caso de IOS, no te presente problemas, pero en aplicaciones hibridas o que muestran los url en una vista interna, como lo hace facebook messenger,facebook, telegram, etc, se presente lo que comentas

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/faq#faq_645353795617467